# I want to change a state on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

i wanted to get this logic =>

if you click on a cube for the first time,
it turns black,
if you clicked another time on the same cube, it turns white.
if the cube is allready white, it becomes black

It should works on each cube individually... I'm getting lost. Thx for your advices.

```js
var compteur = 0;
var hasBeenClick = false;

/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/


$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    //Lorsque je clique
    $(".cliquerAction").click(function () {



        if (hasBeenClick === false) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
            compteur = compteur + 1;
            alert("Premier click" + " vous avez cliqué " + compteur + " fois");
            hasBeenClick = true;

        } else if (hasBeenClick === true) {
            compteur = compteur + 1;
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            alert("Deuxieme click" + " vous avez cliqué " + compteur + " fois");
            hasBeenClick = true;

        }
        if (compteur > 2) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
            alert("Bcp click" + " vous avez cliqué " + compteur + " fois");
            hasBeenClick = false;
            compteur = 0;

        }

    });
});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-color: darkblue;
    max-width: 1980px;
    max-height: 1080px;

}
#page {
    border: white 5px solid;
    width: auto;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
#bloc1 {
 position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#bloc2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#bloc3 {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#bloc4 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#container{
 padding-left:10%;
 padding-right:10%;
 margin:auto;
 border:pink thick solid;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 min-height:500px;
 min-width:500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Page d'acceuil</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="page">
           
             <div id="container">
                    <div id="bloc1" class="cliquerAction" ></div>
                    <div id="bloc2" class="cliquerAction"></div>
                    <div id="bloc3" class="cliquerAction"></div>
                    <div id="bloc4" class="cliquerAction"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think doing with css class is more simple and easy for that background color black and white.Creating two class and use addClass and removeClass as your condition state change

CSS

```
.click-even {
    background: white !important;
}
.click-odd {
    background: black !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    //Lorsque je clique
    $(".cliquerAction").click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("click-odd")){
            $(this).addClass("click-even");
            $(this).removeClass("click-odd");
        }
        else{
             $(this).addClass("click-odd");
            $(this).removeClass("click-even");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to avoid unnecessary confusion, I'm going to suggest an alternative. Instead of checking if something has already been clicked or not to determine the next color, you could instead try focusing only on 3 simple rules based on **the current color and the desired logic you've described**:

1. If a cube is clicked for the first time (e.g. **If it's not black or white**) then change it to black.
2. If a black cube is clicked - it turns white.
3. If a white cube is clicked - it turns black.

Comment: Your logic is much more .... logic, i m gonna do that, thx for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get what i was looking for with this : ( i m sure i can improve this with a switch case, but it s working atm ). Hope this can help someone in somedays.

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/


$(document).ready(function () {
 "use strict";
 //Lorsque je clique



 $(".cliquerAction").click(function () {

  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  alert(color);
  
        //first time applying a color turn it black
  if (color !== "rgb(255, 255, 255)" || "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
  }

        // if it s black and i click on the element : it turns white
  if (color === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  }
        
        // if it s white and i click on the element : it turns black
  if (color === "rgb(255, 255, 255)") {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
  }

 });
});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.black{
    background-color: black;
}

.white{
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color:#aaa;
}

body {
    background-color: darkblue;
    max-width: 1980px;
    max-height: 1080px;

}
#page {
    border: white 5px solid;
    width: auto;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
#bloc1 {
 position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#bloc2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#bloc3 {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#bloc4 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#container{
 padding-left:10%;
 padding-right:10%;
 margin:auto;
 border:pink thick solid;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 min-height:500px;
 min-width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Page d'acceuil</title>

 <script src="../jquery/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div id="page">

  <div id="container">
   <div id="bloc1" class="cliquerAction" class="black" class="white"></div>
   <div id="bloc2" class="cliquerAction" class="black" class="white"></div>
   <div id="bloc3" class="cliquerAction" class="black" class="white"></div>
   <div id="bloc4" class="cliquerAction" class="black" class="white"></div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
```